# I cannot extract exact number of count

Tags: sqlite

When I tried to join, I have a problem.
Below is the my database.

```
rank (id, name)
-----------------
id   |   name
1        CEO
2        CTO
3        Employee
4        Manager

user (id, position)
-----------------
id   |   position
1         2
2         2
3         3
4         3
```

sql >

```
SELECT rank.id, rank.name, count(*) 
      FROM rank
      LEFT JOIN user
      ON rank.id = user.position
      GROUP BY rank.name
```

In this case I have a answer like

```
id    |   name      |   count(*)
1         CEO            1
2         CTO            2
3         Employee       2
4         Manager        1
```

Why `CEO`, `Manager` are counted as '1'?

I think it should be '0'.

Comment: That should be _GROUP BY rank.id, rank.name_ instead of _GROUP BY rank.name_ only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left outer join gives you an empty record whenever there is no match in table user, so you get a count of 1 then instead of 0.

Here is a working select statement:

```
SELECT id, name, (select count(*) from user where user.position = rank.id) as cnt
FROM rank;
```

EDIT: By the way, your statement would work, too, if you counted a user field, because NULL values would not be counted. So you would use COUNT(user.position) instead of COUNT(*). However, I prefer my statement for simplicity and readability.

Answer (score 0):

Left join gives you all rows from the left table, whether or not they match the right one. Since you do count(*) it counts the empty ones, too. You could do count(position) instead, that worked for me.